# Is my understanding and js code about transducer correct

Tags: javascript, clojure, functional-programming

### web articles I've read about transducer

#### Js

- Transducers: Efficient Data Processing Pipelines in JavaScript @ Eric Elliott -Medium
- Understanding Transducers in JavaScript @ Roman Liutikov-Medium

hard to understand from half...

- What's a Transducer?
- Simpler Transducers for JavaScript
- How to make your data transformations more efficient using transducers

#### Clojure

- TRANSDUCERS ARE COMING by Rich Hickey-cognitect
- Transducers-Clojure.org

I read Clojure official tutorial about 2 pages, and understood the basic syntax.  I refered to built-in function reference to understand the transducer example code.

my understanding about above two article is probably 75%...

### my Question

I want to know whether the following understanding/js code is correct or incorrect. Please help me.<(_ _)>

#### About transducer

1. The returned value by `compose()` is a transducer.
2. Transducer is executed by passed to `transduce()` function as argument and, in addition, (2)Transducer is executed by passing array directly to `transducer()`.
3. In (2)'s process, intermediate value isn't generated and efficient process like below link is performed.

   - [Understanding Transducers in JavaScript @ Roman Liutikov -Medium](https://medium.com/@roman01la/understanding-transducers-in-javascript-3500d3bd9624#6a68)

**my code**

```js
"use strict";

const map = fn => arr => arr.map(fn),
filter = fn => arr => arr.filter(fn),
addReducer = arr => arr.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0),
add1 = n => n + 1,
even = n => n % 2 === 0,

compose = (...fns) => initVal => fns.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), initVal),
transduce = (xform, reducer, arr ) => reducer( xform(arr) );



const arr = [1,2,3],
transducer = compose(  /* called transducer or xform */
   map( add1 ), // 2,3,4
   filter( even ), // 2,4
);

console.log( transducer(arr) ) // 2,4
console.log( transduce(transducer, addReducer, arr) ) // 6
```

Comment: `compose` is wrong. WHen you pass `compose(a, b)` it turns into `b(a(initVal))` while it should be applied in reverse order `a(b(initVal))`

Comment: Thank you answering. I understood. compose() is right-associative, and pipe() is left-asicciative, right?

Comment: Yes, you implemented `pipe`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274362/is-my-understanding-of-transducers-correct/52279552#52279552

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transducers take advantage of the fact that function composition abstracts from arity, i.e. can return a function instead of a "normal value":

```js
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));

const add = x => y => x + y;

const sqr = x => x * x;

const add9 = comp(add) (sqr) (3); // returns a lambda

console.log(
  add9(6)); // 15
```

Now a transducer itself is pretty boring:

```
reduce => acc => x => /* body is specific to the transducer at hand */
```

It is just a closure that expects a reducer (i.e. a binary function that combines its two arguments) and can then be fed directly into your favorite reducing function.

Let's take a look at the map transducer:

```
const mapper = f => (reduce => acc => x =>
  reduce(acc) (f(x)));
```

The redundant parenthesis just illustrate the transducer closure. In this case it closes over `f`, our transformation function. Next we are going to apply it:

```js
// map transducer

const mapper = f => reduce => acc => x =>
  reduce(acc) (f(x));

// my favorite fold (reducing function)

const arrFold = alg => zero => xs => {
  let acc = zero;

  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++)
    acc = alg(acc) (xs[i], i);

  return acc;
};

// reducer

const add = x => y => x + y;

// transformer

const sqr = x => x * x;

// MAIN

const main = arrFold(mapper(sqr) (add)) (0);

console.log(
  main([1,2,3])); // 14
```

Well, not that impressive, right? The real power of transducers result from their combination with function composition:

```js
// map transducer

const mapper = f => reduce => acc => x =>
  reduce(acc) (f(x));

// filter transducer

const filterer = p => reduce => acc => x =>
  p(x) ? reduce(acc) (x) : acc;
  
// my favorite fold (reducing function)

const arrFold = alg => zero => xs => {
  let acc = zero;

  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++)
    acc = alg(acc) (xs[i], i);

  return acc;
};

// helpers

const add = x => y => x + y; // reducer
const sqr = x => x * x; // transformer
const isOdd = x => (x & 1) === 1; // predicate
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));

// MAIN

const main = arrFold(comp(filterer(isOdd)) (mapper(sqr)) (add)) (0);

console.log(
  main([1,2,3])); // 10
```

Although we have two transducers involved, there is only a single traversal through the `Array`. This property is called loop fusion. Since the transducer composition returns another function the evaluation order is reversed, i.e. goes from left to right, whereas function composition usually goes from right to left.

Reusability is another advantage. You have to define transducers only once and can use them once and forall with all foldable data types.

It is also noteworthy that `transduce` is just a convenience function and isn't important to understand the concept.

That's pretty much it to say about transducers.

Comment: Thank you answering. I read and try to undersand your answer. very very thanks. Especially two sentences of your answer made me realized: (1)"Transducers take advantage of the fact that function composition abstracts from arity, i.e. can return a function instead of a "normal value.", (2)"It is also noteworthy that transduce is just a convenience function and isn't important to understand the concept."

Answer (score 0):

You code has nothing to do with transducers. Your definition of `filter` and `m̀ap` shows that it uses the normal JS `filter` and `map`

```
const map = fn => arr => arr.map (fn),
const filter = fn => arr => arr.filter (fn),

const combo = compose(map(add1), filter(even));
combo(arr); ==> [2, 4]
```

What happens is that the initial array gets passed to `map` with `add1` which will produce the array `[2, 3, 4]` and then it gets passed to `filter` with `even` and a new array `[2, 4]` created.

The same in transducers:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const add1 = n => n + 1;
const even = n => n% 2 === 0;

const compose = (...fns) => {
  const [firstFunc, ...restFuncs] = fns.reverse();
  return (...args) => restFuncs.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), firstFunc(...args));
};

const mapping = 
  fn => join => (acc, e) => join(acc, fn(e));

const filtering = 
  isIncluded => join => (acc, e) => isIncluded(e) ? join(acc, e) : acc;

const transducer = compose(mapping(add1), filtering(even));
const arrayJoin = (acc, e) => ([...acc, e]);
const result = arr.reduce(transducer(arrayJoin), []);
console.log(result);
```

So the difference is when you pass the `join` to the transducer it's this that happens:

```
mapping(add1)(filtering(even)(arrayAdd))
```

`filtering` is the only step that does add to some collection. When `mapping` calls `join` is calls `filtering` directly. This is why the signatures `(acc, e)` is the same on the work part and the `join` function. When the code runs the adding and filtering is done simultainiously ending up with only one generated array and no intermediate values.

Comment: Thank your answering. Ohh, I get first half of your answer! And now, try to understand latter half. `join` is essencial, key part...(continue to understand now...) very very greaterul!